# How can I output tables to a PDF file with the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, pdf-generation

I want to output a PDF using UIKit's PDF creation methods.  I see plenty of information on the web about creating a graphic context in a PDF, but I want to create smart text tables whose cells the user can later copy and paste into other applications (Word, Excel, etc.).  How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that's not trivial. I recommend you the [libharu](https://github.com/akisute/iPhonePDF) PDF library for iPhone as a good point to start from.